# Why don't synchronous ajax calls in jquery support timeout?

Tags: jquery, ajax, timeout

I was reading [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/ajax-timeout-not-working) that synchronous ajax calls in jquery don't time out.

Is this a technical limitation, or just something the authors didn't feel like supporting? What actually happens under the table when an ajax call is synchronous?

Comment: Basically, during a synchronous ajax request, the browser is blocked and no javascript can be executed while the browser is blocked. Because of this, jQuery can't abort the ajax request after a set timeout because jQuery is javascript and javascript can't be executed while the browser is blocked. This is the primary flaw in synchronous ajax.

Comment: @KevinB - That's the answer I was looking for, which I coincidentally just discovered too. I think the key is that the browser handles the sync/async but not the timeout. If the browser had timeout as part of the XHR api, this wouldn't be a problem

Comment: If you can't move away from synchronous ajax, the second best solution would be to implement a timeout on the server side so that if it takes longer than x seconds, it returns a 500 header.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The browser handles synchronous/asynchronous requests via the [XMLHttpRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) API, but it does not have a built-in timeout feature. JQuery implements its own timeout in JavaScript on top of the browser XHR API.

Since a synchronous call blocks all running scripts, the JQuery timeout does not work. In theory, it seems like synchronous timeouts would be possible if they were implemented at the browser level, as opposed to the JS level.

Answer (score 2):

A synchronous AJAX call blocks until the request has been finished. Implementing a timeout is not possible for technical reasons, because the AJAX call would have to be executed later.

If an AJAX call is executed later, the function somehow has to implement a blocking feature, to stop the code from running further after the AJAX call, and execute it again after a timeout - not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, is something related to the nature of AJAX request, jQuery cannot modify this.

I think timeout should be implemented in the server side in those cases.