# How to set timeout for JQuery $.ajax synchronous request and to do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

if I have a synchronous communication ajax ($.ajax function), how to set a timeout for the ajax.

When the countdown ends, via function or any way to return false.

I want to achieve this approach:

ex:

```
if $.ajax is not timeout 
        => call function A() or do something; 

 else if $.ajax is timeout 
      => call function B() or do something;
```

maybe, detection the working time through other function,ex: javascript setInterval();,setTimeout(); ?

Comment: Look at the right under "Related" section, there is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225597/set-timeout-for-ajax-jquery?rq=1) link, which answers yours question.

Comment: ...seriously, sloth is a mortal sin, doesn't you know?

Comment: where? what is the related section?

Comment: At the right in sidebar. Also, i put the link in my comment.

Comment: I'm sorry I really do not understand this issue..

Comment: where is the sidebar?

Comment: It can't be done as you are using synchronous request - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7919881/why-dont-synchronous-ajax-calls-in-jquery-support-timeout

Comment: yes.., synchronous request

Comment: Than you are out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "url",
  error: function(){
   //error code
  },
  success: function(){
   //success code
  },
  timeout: 3000 //ajax timeout
});
```